# ‘binary_semaphore’ has not been declared in ‘std’

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use c++20 features more exactly  `std::binary_semaphore`. I have installed g++-10 but it does not recognize `binary_semaphore` as an std type. I typed the following command `g++ -std=c++2a` main.cpp -o main.
The error message is:

> error: ‘binary_semaphore’ has not been declared in ‘std’
> 6 | using std::binary_semaphore;

What can I do please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference's compiler support sheet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features), things such as *Atomic waiting and notifying, `std::counting_semaphore`, `std::latch` and `std::barrier`* are supported from GCC 11 onwards. You claim to have GCC 10 installed, which does not support aforementioned features.

Comment: I have just used mutex which is supported in my compiler version. To simulate bianary semaphore I consumed it at first with calling lock so that the task wich want to access must wait passively until an unlock is performed. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @codingamer1997 no problem at all :) Keep in mind that you can quite easily implement `std::counting_semaphore` with a `mutex` and a `condition_variable` :)

Comment: i have gcc 12.2.0 installed but im still getting this error

Comment: @DaniyalAhmadSE did you remember to `#include <semaphore>`? How do you compile your code? What is the distribution of your GCC?